# c# extended control in designer

Tags: c#, controls, designer

I extended a control like so

```
public partial class NewControl : OriginalControl
{

    public NewControl()
    {

    }

}
```

and changed these lines in the MyForm.Designer.cs from

```
private OriginalControl control1;
this.control1 = new OriginalControl();
```

to

```
private NewControl control1;
this.control1 = new NewControl();
```

How ever when I open my form in designer I get this error:

> Failed to load designer. Check the source code for syntax errors and
>   check if all references are available.
>
> ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerLoadException:
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerException:
>   Could not find type 'NewControl'.  Please make sure that the assembly
>   that contains this type is referenced.  If this type is a part of your
>   development project, make sure that the project has been successfully
>   built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, Object codeObject)    at
>   ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.Services.ProjectResourcesComponentCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, Object codeObject)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, Object codeObject)    at
>   ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.Services.ProjectResourcesComponentCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, Object codeObject)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerException:
>   The variable 'control1' is either undeclared or was never
>   assigned.    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)
>
> at
>   ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadDesigner()
>   at
>   ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadAndDisplayDesigner()
>   at
>   ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadInternal(OpenedFile
>   file, Stream stream)    at
>   ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Gui.AbstractViewContentHandlingLoadErrors.Load(OpenedFile
>   file, Stream stream)

How am I extending my control wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may purely be an issue with the namespaces in which these two controls appear. See if a fully qualified class name happens to solve you issue.

Comment: Do you mean "public partial class NewControl : Fully.Qualified.OriginalControl"? Cause that didn't have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: No. I mean 
    private Fully.Qualified.OriginalControl control1;
    this.control1 = new  Fully.Qualified.OriginalControl();